# Docker SSH Connection To LocalHost In RUN Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: hadoop, docker, ssh, openssh

I'm building a docker container for a single node hadoop container, and I'm having a problem setting up the passwordless ssh login for the hadoop user (I'm not using `root` to run the hadoop services). I've been scouring the internet on possible fixes, permissions on authorized_keys, /.ssh, etc all look good. Here are the pertinent parts of the debug logs:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hdadmin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

File permissions before attempting the ssh:

```
drwx------    1 hdadmin  hdadmin       4096 Feb 25 14:33 /home/hdadmin/.ssh
-rw-------    1 hdadmin  hdadmin        402 Feb 25 04:54 authorized_keys
-rw-------    1 hdadmin  hdadmin         87 Feb 25 04:54 config
-rw-------    1 hdadmin  hdadmin       1671 Feb 25 04:54 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 hdadmin  hdadmin        402 Feb 25 04:54 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------    1 hdadmin  hdadmin       1637 Feb 25 04:54 known_hosts
```

And pertinent code from the dockerfile:

```
RUN ... \
&& mkdir -p /home/hdadmin \
&& mkdir -p /home/hdadmin/.ssh \
&& touch /home/hdadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys \
&& touch /home/hdadmin/.ssh/config \
&& touch /home/hdadmin/.ssh/known_hosts \
&& addgroup hadoop \
&& adduser -D -g hadoop -h /home/hdadmin hdadmin -s /etc/passwd \
&& chown -R hdadmin:hdadmin /home/hdadmin \
&& chmod -R 0700 /home/hdadmin \
&& ssh-keygen -A
&& HOST_KEY="$(cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub)" \
&& echo "127.0.0.1 ${HOST_KEY}" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/known_hosts \
&& echo "localhost ${HOST_KEY}" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/known_hosts \
&& echo "$HOSTNAME ${HOST_KEY}" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/known_hosts \
&& echo "0.0.0.0 ${HOST_KEY}"   >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/known_hosts \
&& su-exec hdadmin ssh-keygen -q -N '' -t rsa -f /home/hdadmin/.ssh/id_rsa \
&& cat /home/hdadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys \
&& echo "Host *" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/config \
&& echo -e "\tUser hdadmin" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/config \
&& echo -e "\tPubKeyAuthentication yes" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/config \
&& echo -e "\tIdentityFile /home/hdadmin/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /home/hdadmin/.ssh/config \
&& eval $(ssh-agent) \
&& ssh-add /home/hdadmin/.ssh/id_rsa \
&& chmod 0600 /home/hdadmin/.ssh/* \
&& chmod 0644 /home/hdadmin/.ssh/*.pub \
&& /usr/sbin/sshd \
&& su-exec hdadmin ssh -vvv localhost
```

The sshd_config file is all default, hasn't been modified. Can't figure out why this isn't working, I think I'm doing everything correctly.

EDIT 1: Added more content to dockerfile example.

Comment: do you have the permissions on `.ssh` to 700?

Comment: @man0v I added some more content from the dockerfile, I perform a `chmod -R 0700 /home/hadmin` just before the steps that were previously posted (shown now), which should be setting the permissions on `.ssh`.1

Comment: You should let ssh keygen create the necessary folders for you

Comment: In any case, why not copy what's written here and change the user accounts?
 https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @cricket_007 The major difference with what they've done and what I'm doing is that they're setting up `root` to be the ssh user and thus the user that will run the hadoop services. I'm trying to do this with a new user, `hdadmin`. If I run the setup with `root`, everything works as expected, my issue is trying to do the same thing with a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out. First, I installed a syslog capability so that I could actually view the log messages. This is running on Alpine linux, so I did the following in my dockerfile so I'd get messages:

```
COPY init.sh /tmp/init.sh   # This sh file just contains /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -f /etc/rsyslog.conf & so that it runs in the background
RUN apk add --no-cache rsyslog \
&& echo "\$ModLoad inmark.so" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf \
&& echo "\$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf \
&& echo "auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf \
&& sed -i "s/#LogLevel.*/LogLevel DEBUG/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
&& sed -i "s/#SyslogFacility.*/SyslogFacility AUTH/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
```

Once I did this, in the `/var/log/auth.log` file I found:

```
2018-02-25T19:23:18.942070+00:00 c97682336915 sshd[29]: User hdadmin not allowed because account is locked
```

I didn't set a password for the account, since it wasn't going to be used interactively. So I set one earlier in the dockerfile as such:

```
usermod -p '*' hdadmin
```

Then I got these messages:

```
2018-02-25T19:23:18.942070+00:00 c97682336915 sshd[29]: User hdadmin not allowed because shell /etc/passwd is not executable
```

So I changed the adduser line to be:

```
&& adduser -D -g hadoop -h /home/hdadmin -s /bin/bash hdadmin \
```

Now everything is good. I believe this still leaves the hdadmin account in a state where it can't be used with a password or for any interactive logon, but it can still be used programmatically with public key authentication.